# Display only values containing specific word in array

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, if-statement

Right now I am working on a search function for my json decoded results

The code that I got looks like this:

```
<?php
foreach($soeg_decoded as $key => $val){
    $value = $val["Value"];
    $seotitle = $val["SEOTitle"];
    $text = $val["Text"];

echo '<tr><td>' . $value . '</td><td>' . $seotitle . '</td><td>' . $text . '</td></tr>';
}
?>
```

I want it to only show the results, which contains a specific word, which are stored in a variable named $searchText.

Is there any functions or commands, which can seperate all the results, and only show the results which contains the word stored in $searchText.

Something like this:

```
if($value OR $seotitle OR $text contains $searchText){
    echo '<tr><td>' . $value . '</td><td>' . $seotitle . '</td><td>' . $text . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `substr_count()`

```
<?php
foreach($soeg_decoded as $key => $val){
    $value = $val["Value"];
    $seotitle = $val["SEOTitle"];
    $text = $val["Text"];

  if(substr_count($value, $searchText) || substr_count($seotitle, $searchText) ||  substr_count($text, $searchText)){
      echo '<tr><td>' . $value . '</td><td>' . $seotitle . '</td><td>' . $text . '</td></tr>';
  }

}
?>
```

Read more at:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Comment: Thanks!!! I added a if before, so it also could contain an empty searchText variable. This helped me alot!!

Comment: strpos() might be a cheaper operation since it looks for the first occurrence. You don't need seem to be needing the count and substr_count() will be reading the whole string to find the occurrences which is more expensive.

Answer (score 3):

This would probably be the simplest way to do it:

```
$row = '<tr><td>' . $value . '</td><td>' . $seotitle . '</td><td>' . $text . '</td></tr>';
if (empty($searchText) || strpos($searchText, $row) !== false) {
    echo $row;
}
```

This could have false matches if `$searchText` contains `<td>` or something, if you are concerned about that you could do:

```
if (count(array_filter([$value, $seotitle, $text], function($v) use ($searchText) {
    return empty($searchText) || strpos($searchText, $v) !== false;
}))) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $value . '</td><td>' . $seotitle . '</td><td>' . $text . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is kind of what i was looking for :D

But is there a way to make it show the row, even if the searchText is empty? Because it is not needed to write a searchText :)

Comment: See edit, it will show if searchText is empty or if not empty, if it matches searchText

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using `strpos()`:-

```
if(strpos($value,$searchText) !== FALSE || strpos($seotitle,$searchText) !== FALSE || strpos($text,$searchText) !== FALSE){
    echo '<tr><td>' . $value . '</td><td>' . $seotitle . '</td><td>' . $text . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **strpos**  string function to check if the $searchText (Needle) is part of $value/$seotitle/$text (Haystack).

```
if ((strpos($value,$searchText) !== false) or 
(strpos($seotitle,$searchText) !== false) or 
(strpos($text,$searchText) !== false)) 
{
    echo '<tr><td>' . $value . '</td><td>' . $seotitle . '</td><td>' . $text . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: It looks like there was a flood of similar answers, while I was typing this!